# Android Studio "Cannot Resolve Symbol "xxx" "

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I import other`s project and this problem occurs again, It has confused me for one month.

the problems show like this

[Some imported packages become red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f49Wz.png)

But I do find the file in my SDK Browser file like this ‘LocalLog’:

[LocalLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCe1d.png)

I have tried a lot of methods including invalidate cashes / delete .idea and .gradle, which didn`t work for me. So how can I solve this annoyed problem?

My gradle version is 6.1.1

My Gradle Plugin Version is 4.0.0

My SDK version is 28

The gradle configuation shows in the code:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        buaacntlab {
            keyAlias 'cntlab_insight'
            keyPassword 'insight_cnt_lab_'
            storeFile file('D:/ProgramData/Android/Projects/buaacntlab.jks')
            storePassword 'cntlabbuaa'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.github.clearsights.fmpdrtest"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.buaacntlab
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.buaacntlab
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0"

    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.1.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in android gradle plugin v4.0.0 they removed the need for this configuration of using `jniLibs.srcDirs` [as mentioned in the changelog here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?buildsystem=cmake#configure-external-build). You can now get rid of that sourceSets block.

> External native build now automatically packages those libraries, so
> explicitly packaging the library with jniLibs results in a duplicate.
> To avoid the build error, move the prebuilt library to a location
> outside jniLibs or remove the jniLibs configuration from your
> build.gradle file.

Alternatively, you can downgrade to gradle 3.6.0 and re-compile and it should work. In fact, you can play around by downgrading first, build an app and note down the APK size, and then upgrade and build again to notice the difference.